# How to cast an address to a contract instance

Tags: solidity

I want to clear an address of the contract in my smart contract, under some condition. Here is minimal reproducable code:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Test {
    IERC20 test;

    function clearTest() public {
        test = address(0x0); // compiler is not happy with this nor IERC20(0x0)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh this for me: `delete test`

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Test {
    IERC20 public test ;

    function clearTest() public {
        delete test;
    }

}
```